# Fix a string from supplied data

Tags: c#, regex

Let's say I have these items in a list full of strings:

- Cash
- Cheque
- Postal Order
- Credit Card
- Bank Transfer
- etc... etc... etc...

I found a nice thing called "LevenshteinDistance".
This is working up to some point. It does not always return the correct string if I type something wrong.

I am thinking of going to the Regex side to get this.

Basically I want to type, for example, "chq" and it should return "Cheque".

I have this code to try this but it is also not working correctly:

```
foreach (string entry in lsbSuppliedData.Items)
{
    entr = entry.Trim().Replace(" ", "");
    regex = new Regex("^[" + inputString + "]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (regex.IsMatch(inputString))
    {
        proposal = entry;
        //break;
    }
}
```

Can someone please just help me into the right direction? I have a list with the items it should suggest, which at max would be 20 items (not very big, so performance is not a big issue).

Comment: What exactly is not working correctly?

Comment: Are you looking for a soundex search function like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22464377/215752

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var words = new[] { "Cash", "Cheque" ... };

string search = "chq";

var results = words
             .Where(x => x.ToLower()
                        .Intersect(search.ToLower().Distinct()).Count() >= search.Length);
```

This would work and ignore the case sensitivity and also the order of letters for ex if you type `cqh` it will still return `Cheque`, if you don't want this to happen, it requires much more work.Also you can change `Where` to `First` or `FirstOrDefault` if you want to get a single result instead of all matches.

Update: Here is another version that doesn't ignore the order of letters:

```
var result = words
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToLower().Where(search.Contains).SequenceEqual(search));
```

Comment: You could use `First()` and then with lazy evaluation it will run faster

Comment: @Hogan I assume he is looking for more than one result

Comment: Ah ok, But you are just returning a true false anyway so is there a semantic difference?

Comment: @Jonesy good point thanks. Hogan I think OP wants to get result string,not just true of false, _Basically I want to type, for example, "chq" and it should return "Cheque"._

_

Comment: I am getting errors at ToLower and search. I am not very familiar with LINQ (if this is linq).